# Connecting and getting mysql connection object

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql

I have written this code that connects to a mysql database. The function should be able to be used as a context manager - via `with`. It is working, but I am not sure if this is a great way of doing it.

`conect.py`

```
import os
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import contextlib

_CFG = {
  'user': os.getenv("MYSQL_USER"),
  'password': os.getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
  'host': os.getenv("MYSQL_SERVER"),
  'database': os.getenv("SENSOR_DB"),
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}

@contextlib.contextmanager
def _connect(db=None):
    if db:
        _CFG["database"] = db

    try:
        print("{usr} connecting to {db} on {host}.".format(
            usr=_CFG["user"],
            db=_CFG["database"],
            host=_CFG["host"]
            )
        )
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**_CFG)
        yield connection
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)
        yield None
    else:
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Obvious (dumb) point - I'd suggest using `logging` instead of `print`
2. I would have some kind of builder for `_CFG` so I could choose if I use environment variables for configuration or something else
3. Instead of `str.format`, you may want to use fstring: `f"{_CFG["user"]} connecting to {_CFG["database"]} on {_CFG["host"]}."`
4. Instead of `yield None` you may want to reraise exception (from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html), "*If an exception is trapped merely in order to log it or to perform some action (rather than to suppress it entirely), the generator must reraise that exception*"). Otherwise, your code will fail with a funny exception.

Comment: I was wondering even if the `_connect` function acts as context manger , should I just call it at module level instead of using `with` inside a function, then the connection object will be available at multiple functions ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I think that if you want to have a shared connection in multiple functions, you would rather not use a context manager at all, but some other patterns to handle this. But why would you want this? I would not bother unless I am sure there's some significant performance impact, but I don't think there would be.

Comment: Ok, cool thanks I tried yesterday and didn’t find any significant benefit so switched back.